# Debug Levels Rails - The level ":debug" show all logs. I want ONLY ERRORS. Is it possible?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-4-2-1

I have an app in AWS Ec2 and I want to see the errors ( 500, 502, 50x, 403, 404 etc. ) ina  log file.

The file `config / environments / production.rb`

Have the code:

```
config.log_level = :debug
```

I tried to change this to `:warn, :info, :error, :fatal`.
Really this values shows ONLY ERRORS, but the information is very limited.

The value `:debug` shows many datails, but... Shows all logs too...

I am seeing the erros log here:

```
EC2 ROOT: cd /var/log/nginx
CMD: tail -f error.log
```

There are another log folder, inside the app, here:

```
{appfolder}/current/log/production.log
```

But this file is empty. The logs are not being saved here.

Some informations:

```
ruby -v: 2.2.2p95
rails -v: 4.2.1
OS: Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
```

Tks everyone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the [the official documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.14/debugging_rails_applications.html#log-levels),

in your **#config/environments/production.rb** you can add/change the **log_level** like this

```
  # Use the lowest log level to ensure availability of diagnostic information
  # when problems arise.
  # :debug, :info, :warn, :error, and :fatal
  config.log_level = :error
```

I hope that this helps

Happy Hacking

Answer (score 0):

Check Logger class http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html. Just use log level suitable for you.